# Why is (n+1)/2n = 1/2 + 1/n, and not 1/2 + 1/2n?

Tags: fractions

If I factor $(n+1)/2n$ by $n$, I get $n(1+1/n)/n(2)$. Simplifying, I end up with $(1 + 1/n) / 2$.

This can be rewritten as: $1/2 + (1/n)/2$, which would give me $1/2 + (1/n) \times (1/2) = 1/2 + 1/(2n)$.

Why is this wrong? I'm told: $(n+1) / (2n) = 1/2 + 1/n$ ?

Comment: The fraction is $\frac{n+1}{2n}$? That is indeed $\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your n+1/2n represents $\frac{n+1}{2n}$, then we have$$\frac{n+1}{2n}=\frac{n}{2n}+\frac{1}{2n}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2n}$$
because
$$\frac {A+B}{C}=\frac{A}{C}+\frac{B}{C}.$$

Comment: Incredibly fast answers. I'm still trying to figure out how to write mathjax and you've already answered. Thank you!

Comment: @Sam: You are welcome.

Comment: @Sam: consider upvoting and accepting if you are satisfied with the answer :)

Comment: @anderstood Upvoting requires 15 reputation and a registered account. Sam can't do that (yet, at least).

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah OK, but can he accept?

Comment: @anderstood Yes, accepting is possible (unless Sam lost the cookies for the unregistered account to which this question belongs).

Comment: accepted :) Thank you all for the help!